# How to fix the error "PHP Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER"?

Tags: php, oracle, error-handling

I have an autofill current date column in php. It goes to the oracle database further. After the form submission I get the above error.

Here's the code:

```
<form class="cmxform" action ='functions/processform.php' id="Form1" method="post">
<legend> Add Member</legend>
            <label for="addname">Select*</label>
           <select class="form-control" name="school" id="school">
                <?php
                $names = $getnames->getnames();
                oci_execute($names, OCI_DEFAULT);
                while ($row = oci_fetch_array($names, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['NAME'] . '">' . $row['NAME']. '</option>';
                }
                ?>
           </select>
                <div class="form-row">

                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="fName">First Name* </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fName" name="fName" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="mName">Middle Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mName" name="mName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="lName">Last Name* </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lName" name="lName" required>
                    </div>
               
             <div class="form-row">
                <input type="radio" id="p" name="paidunpaid" value="p">
                <label for="paid">Paid</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="female" name="paidunpaid" value="u">
                <label for="unpaid">Unpaid</label><br>
             </div>
                    
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="date">Date</label>
<input name="date" id="date" required type="text" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>" />
</div>
</div>
 <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="Id">Id </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Id" name="Id">
  </div>
  </div>   
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-primary" type="submit">Add Role</button>
```

processform.php

```
$fName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "fName", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$lName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "lName", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$mName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "mName", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Id", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$school = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "school", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$paidunpaid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "paidunpaid", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$dt = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "dt", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
 $dbUser = "xxxx";
$dbPass = "xxxx";
$dbConn = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xxxx)))";
$conn = oci_connect($dbUser, $dbPass, $dbConn);
 $sql =oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO person (LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, ID, Primaryschool, Paidunpaidposition,date)                              
     VALUES(:lName,:fName,:mName, :id, :school, :paidunpaid, :date)");
oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':dt', $dt);
oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':fName', $fName);
oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':lName', $lName);
oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':mName', $mName);
oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':id', $id);
oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':school', $school);
oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':paidunpaid', $paidunpaid);
$result = oci_execute($sql);
 if ($result) {
        echo 
        '<script >
            alert("Thank you for registration.");
            window.location = "http://google.com/";
        </script>';
    
        return true;
    } else {
        echo '
        <script>
            alert("Error, please try submitting again. Error code 1");
            window.history.back();
        </script>';
        return false;
    }
```

I have updated the entire code as one error leads to another. I am new to php any help would be apprecidated. And I am writing this as I can't post so much of code just for one error. Needed some text to update the rest of the code. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to bind string instead of date data type.
Modify it as follows

```
$sql =oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO person (date)                              
     VALUES(to_date(:dt,'dd/mm/yyyy'))");
oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':dt', $date);
```

Comment: Okay. Made the change. Now I get "PHP Warning:  oci_execute(): ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name"

Comment: @AAM check that your variable name in sql is equal to the one from oci_bind_by_name

Comment: @AAM ah, I see, you can't use 'date' as a variable name. Please look at my updated my answer - I've replaced `:date` with `:dt`

Comment: I did that. Now it says "oci_execute(): ORA-00936: missing expression" on the bind_by_name line

Comment: Okay I have updated the entire form. Please check. Thank you

Comment: I still see :date there. Replace it with :dt

Comment: Yes I have made the changes suggested by you. The lasta error that I have got is the mising expression one